# Issue connecting to RTSP stream from wowza

Tags: rtsp

I'm having an issue connecting my wowza server to an axis encoder via RTSP. It's an M7001 encoder with up to date firmware (5.20.1)

I'm using a connection of the format:

rtsp://root:password@IPADDRESS/media.amp

The exact same connection string works correctly from VLC media player.  When I look at the stream codec information, it would seem there are two streams.
Stream 0 - which is empty
Stream 1 - which contains the actual video, and which plays properly with VLC

Wowza seems only to try and play stream 0, and therefore shows only a blank screen.  Is there a parameter I can add to the URL force it to use stream 1?

I've attached a screenshot showing the stream infor from VLC.

[image: Codec Information from VLC]

Answer (score 1):

After much poking and prodding, the problem was actually packet size.

The M7001 video encoder was is connected to our wowza server via a VPN connection. The VPN overhead results in a reduced MTU, less than 1200 in this particular case.  Once I reduced the MTU in the axis encoder, everything behaved properly.

In this case, VLC's awesomeness, in being able to negotiate an alternative connection when the  initial connection failed, made it tricky to see what was actually happening.

The MTU settings are also not available by the regular web interface, you can get to it via:

System Options > Advanced > Plain Config

And then find the MTU setting.